# Outsystems: Dynamic Tree view from DB data/list

Tags: treeview, forge, outsystems

I am trying to use the TreeView available inside Forge but it seems complicates and the data list is based only on structures but not database data. So, I would like to know if there is some **dynamic** TreeView or hierarchical view component (based on database's records) that I can use for user role management?

Answer (score 1):

There are several Tree components in the Forge, but I do not see one called "TreeView".  Can you tell me which you are referring to?  Also, I suggest posting on the Forge component's Support tab, which will probably get you more answers.

Comment: Hi Craig,  sorry for the inconvenience, I have mentioned the field name but not the component name from Forge. Just search with text' tree' then the first component and the name of the component is "Tree Widget". And I have tried the following components also 1.zTree 2.JsTree 3.Hierarchical Tree 4.jsTree widget etc.